# Can a function have n outputs or a' set' as an image?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

In my trigonometry text the author says that significance of trignometrical functions is that they wind real plane onto the trigonometric circle(unit circle)

Let $ S ={(x,y): x^2 + y ^2 = 1} $

The trigonometric functions $ t(x) : R\rightarrow S$

SO I am confused and also sparked up by the this intro:I gues I am interpreting the statement $ t(x) : R\rightarrow S$
 wrong way(kindly correct me)

But It made me curious can we have function that have multiple outputs or return a set as an unique image?

**FYI : BOOK NAME:** Trigonometric FUnctions by A.Panchiskin

Comment: A [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) is a "recipe" that to each input "associates" **exactly one** output. Of course, we may have functions with input a number or a pair of numbers or set, .... and the same for the output.

Comment: The mapping associates to every real number $t \in \mathbb R$ a point $P_t$ on the unit circle $S$. See page 12 : "This mapping is **not** one-to-one", i.e. every point on $S$ is "used" infinitely many times.

Comment: This means that the mapping is not "invertible", i.e. from a point $P$ on $S$ we cannot recover $t$...

Answer (score 1):

In a strict sense a function can only output one value, as mentioned in the comments on your question.

However in your example the outputs of the function $t$ are ordered pairs $(x,y)$, so could be easier to think of it having *two* outputs.

Of course we are not limited to only two; e.g. we could have a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and think of it having $n$ outputs. Remember though that really there is only one output, which is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If you read the definition of a function you will see there is no restriction as to what kind of elements can be in the range, so function can output sets as well, e.g. $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ for example.